# How to do a 2-step wrangling and nesting using tidyr/dplyr, using %>% pipe only?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I need to accomplish a wrangling task with `tidyr`/`dplyr` as part of a `%>%` pipe. That is, *without* assigning data to helper objects. I have the following `trb` *tibble* as a given:

```r
library(tibble)

trb <-
  tribble(~name,     ~type,    ~dat,
        "john",    "cat",    mtcars,
        "john",    "spider", Puromycin,
        "amanda",  "dog",    ToothGrowth,
        "chris",   "wolf",   PlantGrowth,
        "annie",   "lion",   women,
        "richard", "frog",   trees,
        "liz",     "horse",  USArrests,
        "raul",    "snake",  iris,
        "kate" ,   "bear",   quakes)
```

and I want to do a 2-step wrangling (not necessarily in the following order):

1. lump together *john*'s `dat` data frames into a named list (in which names will come from `type`); and
2. shift john's information to leftmost while nesting the data of the others.

The desired output should therefore be:

```r
desired_output <-
  tribble(~dat_john,                                  ~other_people,
          list("cat" = mtcars, "spider" = Puromycin), trb %>% dplyr::filter(name != "john")
        )
```

As noted above, it's important to me to get from `trb` to `desired_output` using `%>%` only. Any ideas?

Comment: So you want a list in the first column `dat_john` but a tibble in the other column? I'm unclear on what you're looking for to generate the result in a more direct way than your code already does.

Comment: So to clarify/confirm, you want to get a different data type for the two columns: a list of named tibbles on the left, and a nested tibble on the right?

Comment: @JonSpring, yes, correct. exactly like `desired_output`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this? It first categorizes the data as `john` or not, then nests all the data for each category into one list, then pivots those two categories wide.

```
library(tidyr); library(dplyr)
trb %>%
  mutate(column = if_else(name == "john", "dat_john", "other people")) %>%
  nest(-column) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = column, values_from = data) %>%
  # from @ekoam's answer, to convert this column to named list
  mutate(dat_john = with(dat_john[[1L]], list(setNames(dat, type))))
```

Comment: I like it! Simple and intuitive!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve what you want via a sequence of pipelines. But I am not sure why you want to do this. Note that you need to manually assign "john" as the first level and rearrange the dataframe. Otherwise, if "john" is not the first entry, you won't get him to the leftmost after `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

trb %>% 
  group_by(id = factor(name != "john", labels = c("dat_john", "other_people"))) %>% 
  arrange(id) %>% # use factor and arrange to ensure that john is always the first level
  nest(data = -id) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = data) %>% 
  mutate(dat_john = with(dat_john[[1L]], list(setNames(dat, type))))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
  dat_john         other_people    
  <list>           <list>          
1 <named list [2]> <tibble [7 x 3]>
```